# javadoc @value annotation issue in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

I've read a lot here but didn't find the answer. I faced a problem with a **`@value`** Javadoc annotation.

IDE: Eclipse Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)

If I place it on the `String` variable it is ok and works properly, but if the variable is `Integer` then everything is bad.

Here is a code where variables stand side by side:

```
/**
 * Default delimiter. {@value #DEFAULT_LIST_SEPARATOR}
 */
public final static String DEFAULT_LIST_SEPARATOR = ",";

/**
 * Default int value. {@value #START_VALUE}
 */
public final static Integer START_VALUE = 20000;
```

and for the first variable description shows properly, but for the other, I see only `{@value #START_VALUE}`.

Where am I wrong, guys?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If **`Integer` instead of `int`** is used, `@value` is not resolved.

In your example, the constant `START_VALUE` is an object of the type `Integer` which wraps the value `20000`. So the question is, **does `@value` support autoboxing?** The [Java Language Specification does not cover Javadoc comments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.7). There seems to be no formal specification for Javadoc, just the following simple description for `@value` which does not answer the question:

> [Displays constant values.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html)

If using the **the Javadoc tool of the Oracle Java SDK** to generate HTML **as de facto standard**, `@value` is allowed for `int`, but not for the type `Integer`. The Javadoc tools of Oracle's Java 8 and Java 9 Development Kit report the same error:

```
error: value does not refer to a constant
   * Default int value. {@value #START_VALUE}
                        ^
```

If using `{@value}` instead of `{@value #START_VALUE}` the error becomes `error: {@value} not allowed here`.

Let's have a look at following cases:

```
public class JavadocValue {

    /** STRING = {@value} */
    public final static String STRING = "lorem ipsum";

    /** STRING_CONCATENATION = {@value} */
    public final static String STRING_CONCATENATION = "lorem" + " ipsum";

    /** STRING_COMPUTATION = {@value} */
    public final static String STRING_COMPUTATION = System.getProperty("path.separator");

    /** INT = {@value} */
    public final static int INT = 42;

    /** INT_COMPUTATION = {@value} */
    public final static int INT_COMPUTATION = (20 + 1) * 2;

    /** INTEGER = {@value} */
    public final static Integer INTEGER = 42;

    /** INTEGER_COMPUTATION = {@value} */
    public final static Integer INTEGER_COMPUTATION = Integer.valueOf("42");

    /** ENUM = {@value} */
    public final static MyEnum ENUM = MyEnum.VALUE_B;
    public enum MyEnum { VALUE_A, VALUE_B };

}
```

**In Eclipse `@value` is resolved as it is in** the Oracle **Javadoc tool**:

```
STRING = "lorem ipsum"
STRING_CONCATENATION = "lorem ipsum"
STRING_COMPUTATION = [error/unresolved]
INT = 42
INT_COMPUTATION = 42
INTEGER = [error/unresolved]
INTEGER_COMPUTATION = [error/unresolved]
ENUM = [error/unresolved]
```

Conclusion: **Use `@value` for constants of a primitive type or of `String` only**.

Comment: yeah @howlger, apparently you're right. Thansk for relpy. And yes, a knew about _{@value}_

Comment: By the way when I replaced _Integer_ with _int_ it's really helped

Comment: I've examined it in more detail: Eclipse behaves exactly like the Javadoc tool (see my edited answer).

Answer (score 0):

With Intellij IDEA 2017.2.6 code above works fine:
[image]

So, it may be just `eclipse` bug.

Comment: probably is. They had some problems with javadoc before. Anyway thanks for reply

Comment: No, it isn't. Don't trust advertising promises, generate HTML Javadoc and you will see.

Answer (score 0):

Do a clean project and an eclipse restart :) it may work well after these :)