# Javadoc {@value} not working for Constants

Tags: java, constants, javadoc

I am trying to apply Javadoc to a constant variable.

The code:

```java
private final String playerName;

/**
 * The value of MAX_PLAYER_HEALTH is {@value} 
 */
 
private static final Integer MAX_PLAYER_HEALTH = 200;

/**
 * The value of DEFAULT_PLAYER_LIVES {@value}
 */
private static final Integer DEFAULT_PLAYER_LIVES = 3;

private Integer health = MAX_PLAYER_HEALTH;
private int lives = DEFAULT_PLAYER_LIVES;
```

With this once I generate the Javadoc I get an error:

```
C:\Users\AmirS\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TheTower\src\PlayerSingleton\PlayerSingleton.java:22: error: {@value} not allowed here
     * The value of DEFAULT_PLAYER_LIVES {@value}
C:\Users\AmirS\OneDrive\Documents\NetBeansProjects\TheTower\src\PlayerSingleton\PlayerSingleton.java:18: error: {@value} not allowed here
     * The value of MAX_PLAYER_HEALTH is {@value}
```

I am following the [reference guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#%7B@value%7D) on Oracle. What is it that I am doing wrong?

UPDATED CODE: Changed `Integer` to `int`. `{@value}` can only be used with primitive types and not wrappers such as `Integer`.

Comment: Maybe related issue?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47480314/javadoc-value-annotation-issue-in-eclipse

Comment: Using Eclipse and JDK14 - the @value tag only seems to work for primitives.

Comment: @stridecolossus Your link has helped me. The problem was using Integer instead of int in my constant variable. Thank you.

Comment: Please post your solution *as an answer* and accept that, instead of putting it into your question and adding “Solved” to the title.

Comment: yep, they are a new contributor so i added an answer for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was using `Integer` instead of `int` in your constant variable.

Comment: I will upvote this as the answer, I have added EDIT and Solution in my question.

Comment: @AMhere Your question should just be the question. No point in editing the answer in, when it's perfectly fine here. Accept and upvote  please, this is how stackoverflow works.