# @value tag reference to another class

Tags: java, javadoc

I am generating some javadoc comments for a few utility methods that I created.

How can I use the `@value` tag to reference the actual value of a constant that is defined in another class?

For example:

My constants class

```
public class Constants {
   public static final String SOME_CONSTANT = "theVal";
}
```

My utility class

```
public class CoolUtil {

   /**
    *
    * @return a MyObj based on {@value #Constants.SOME_CONSTANT}
    */
   public static MyObj generateIt(){
       ...
   }  

}
```

I want the viewer of the javadoc to see `Returns: a MyObj based on 'theVal'`

The syntax that I'm using now doesn't seem to work. If I have the constant defined inside the `CoolUtil` class, the `@value` annotation works, but I don't want to have to create a duplicate reference to the constant.

Any help/tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

According to the doc https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#link

> When used with argument package.class#field in any doc comment, it displays the value of the specified constant

In your case:

```
/**
*
* @return a MyObj based on {@value com.yourpackage.Constants#SOME_CONSTANT}
*/
public static MyObj generateIt()
```

Comment: just gave it a try, but doesn't seem to work. it displays as {@value ...} which is the actual path that I typed. Interestingly, it does seem to be aware of the constant that I'm referencing because after I type the # it offers me the list of the defined constants. So I think I have the right package syntax, something just isn't resolving quite right.

Comment: This seems to work in my IntelliJ, which IDE are you using?

Comment: eclipse ver 4.13.0

Comment: Seem like a eclipse bug https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47480314/javadoc-value-annotation-issue-in-eclipse